# How to convert Excel file to Java object

Tags: java

I am looking for a jar file that convert Excel file to an Java object, similar to javax.xml.bind.
I use eBay.xcelite but it can convert only by sheet as object and row as attributes.
And i want to specify the object type by cell X data.

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the library which can help you to do it
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html

Answer (score 0):

There is one framework, [Poiji](https://github.com/ozlerhakan/poiji), to convert Excel rows to Java objects. It uses Apache POI internally. We use it for our purpose.